# how can I update the col 'mark' in df1 with col 'mark' in df2

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
there are two dataframes df1,df2, and they both have the same col 'name',

import  pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'name':list('bacgh'),'mark':[0,0,0,0,0]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'name':list('abecgh'),'mark':[12,46,66,77,37,54]})
print(df1)
print(df2)
'''
  name  mark
0    b     0
1    a     0
2    c     0
3    g     0
4    h     0
  name  mark
0    a    12
1    b    46
2    e    66
3    c    77
4    g    37
5    h    54
```

'''

**>    # Note: the order of row in df1  can not be changed!    # how can I

> update the col 'mark' in df1 with col 'mark' in df2
>
> ```
> and get the following results:**
> ```

```
   name  mark
0    b     46
1    a     12
2    c     77
3    g     37
4    h     54

'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
print(df1[['name']].merge(df2))
```

Output

```
  name  mark
0    b    46
1    a    12
2    c    77
3    g    37
4    h    54
```